# BIOS doesn't read IOS file from USB drive

Tags: linux, operating-system, system, system-administration

I am currently having Linux Ubuntu running on my machine. I want to dual boot it with Linux Kali, however, after sticking USB drive I see EFI amongst boot options, when I select EFI.

*What I have done step by step:*

- Created bootable USB using commands:

  - `sudo umount /dev/sdX`
  - `sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/kali.iso of=/dev/sdX status=progress oflag=sync`
- Booting from Kali Linux USB stick

*What I get:*

1. After pressing **F9** to select Boot Options.
2. I see **EFI** options, I click it.
3. Therefore I see `<ubuntu>` and `<BOOT>` options. I click `<BOOT>`, then I see these files:

   - mmx64.efi
   - fbx64.efi
   - BOOTX64.EFI

*What I tried:*

1. I checked `Boot Order`, so USB drive comes first.
2. `Secure Boot` is disabled.
3. Tried creating bootable USB drive again.
4. I tried clicking the above mentioned files: *mmx64.efi, fbx64.efi, BOOTX64.EFI*, it does not help.

### Note:

I am using `HP OMEN`, 32GB USB drive, Linux Ubuntu runs perfectly on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

### ISSUE FIXED

The problem was in the process of creating bootable USB drive. I was using `Ventoy`, after I tried using `Startup Disk Creator`, it is default app in Linux Ubuntu. Everything is as expected now.